# Using MYSQL to select rows in which part of a column matches part of an input

Tags: sql, mysql, where-clause, intersection, find-in-set

I have a database in which one of the columns contains a series of information 'tags' about the row that are stored as a comma-separated list (a string) of dynamic length. I am using mysqli within PHP, and I want to select rows in which any of these items match any of the items in an input string.

For example, there could be a row describing an apple, containing the tags: "tasty, red, fruit, sour, sweet, green." I want this to show up as a result in a query like: `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE info tags IN ('blue', 'red', 'yellow')"`, because it has at least one item ("red") overlapping. Kind of like "array_intersect" in PHP.

I think I could use `IN` if each row had only one tag, and I could use `LIKE` if I used only one input tag, but both are of dynamic length. I know I can loop over all the input tags, but I was hoping to put this in a single query. Is that possible? If not, can I use a different structure to store the tags in the database to make this possible (something other than a comma separated string)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best would be to create `tags` table (id + label) then separate "table_tags" table which holds table_id and tag_id.
that means using JOINS to get the final result.

another (but lazy) solution would be to prefix and suffix tags with commas so the full column contains something like:

```
,tasty,red,fruit,sour,sweet,green,
```

and you can do a LIKE search without being worried about overlapping words (i.e red vs bored) and still get a proper match by using `LIKE '%,WORD,%'`